# Proper way tho change file associations using VBS?

Tags: vbscript, file-association

How can I remove or change ALL file associations for certain application ?

For example I have MS office 2007 installed and I want to remove all file associations which are associated with Office package or at least those which are associated with certain exe files from office package.
I need this for various apps not just Office.

Best regards, Primoz

Answer (score 1):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objShell
set objShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")

'Change this line
addFileAssociation ".txt", "notepad.exe"

Sub addFileAssociation( fileExt, whichApp )
If ( Left(fileExt, 1) <> "." ) Then
fileExt = "." & fileExt
End If
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & fileExt & "\Application", whichApp
End Sub
```

Comment: You can multiply the addFileAssociation line for as many extensions you need to replace...